# DCMTK library with qt in mac

Tags: c++, macos, qt, dcmtk

i have installed DCMTK through brew and i have configured it on qt adding the path directed to the library. When i try to open a DICOM image and run the project, i have these 2 errors: 
`Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "DicomImage::DicomImage(char const*, unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long)", referenced from:
      MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked() in mainwindow.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [testDicom.app/Contents/MacOS/testDicom] Error 1
21:04:21: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project testDicom (kit: Desktop Qt 5.12.1 clang 64bit)
When executing step "Make"
21:04:21: Elapsed time: 00:00.`
How can i solve it?

UPDATE (this is my file.pro):

```
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2019-04-24T20:43:01
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = testDicom
TEMPLATE = app

# The following define makes your compiler emit warnings if you use
# any feature of Qt which has been marked as deprecated (the exact warnings
# depend on your compiler). Please consult the documentation of the
# deprecated API in order to know how to port your code away from it.
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

# You can also make your code fail to compile if you use deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
# You can also select to disable deprecated APIs only up to a certain version of Qt.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

CONFIG += c++11

SOURCES += \
        main.cpp \
        mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS += \
        mainwindow.h

INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/Cellar/dcmtk/3.6.4/include \


LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib \
        -L/usr/local/Cellar/dcmtk/3.6.4/lib \
        -L/usr/local/Cellar/dcmtk/3.6.4/bin


FORMS += \
        mainwindow.ui

# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i have added my .pro file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problems solved, i post here the solution because it could be helpful for someone. 
When you include the dcmtk you have also to include zlib and libiconv.

INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/Cellar/dcmtk/3.6.4/include \
               /usr/local/opt/zlib/lib/include

LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib \
        -L/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/4.1.0_1/lib \
        -L/usr/local/Cellar/dcmtk/3.6.4/lib \
        -ldcmdata \
        -ldcmimgle \
        -ldcmjpeg \
        -loflog \
        -ldcmpstat \
        -lofstd \
        -liconv \
        -lz